# Translate Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, scipy

I translated this matlab code:

```
Down_step = 2;
aveKernel = fspecial('average',2);
aveY1 = conv2(Y1, aveKernel,'same');
aveY2 = conv2(Y2, aveKernel,'same');
Y1 = aveY1(1:Down_step:end,1:Down_step:end);
Y2 = aveY2(1:Down_step:end,1:Down_step:end);
```

to Python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import convolve as __convolve

Down_step = 2   
aveKernel = np.array([[1.0,1.0],[1.0,1.0]])/4 # averaging filter
aveY1 = __convolve(ref, aveKernel, mode='constant', cval=0.0) 
aveY2 = __convolve(dist, aveKernel, mode='constant', cval=0.0)
```

I don't know how to translate the last two lines, the

```
1:Down_step:end
```

part confuses me, what does it mean?

Comment: `Y1 = aveY1(::Down_step, ::Down_step)` and so on. [`This`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/user/basics.indexing.html#other-indexing-options) might be worth a read.

Comment: thank you! I think there should be [ ] instead of ( )

Comment: do you think it is correct to translate 'same' with  mode='constant', cval=0.0 ?